# End tag div seen-validator

Tags: html, validation

I have some problems with tag "div" on my web-site in validator:
Unclosed element div:  and

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="component">
                <section class="block1">
                    <div class="container">
                        <header class="flex-between-center">
                            <div class="left">
                                <p><span class="icon icon-map"></span>1620 Pebblewood Ln. Ste. 132
                                    <br> Naperville, IL 60563
                                </p>
                                <a class="tel" ><span class="icon icon-phone"></span><b>(630)741-4445</b></a>
                                <div class="mob-tel">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="/">
                                    <img src="<?=CONFIG::TEMPLATE_ROOT?>design/img/logo.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <form action="/search">
                                <span class="input input--hoshi search-wrapp">
                                    <input class="input__field input__field--hoshi" type="text" id="search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search..."/>
                                    <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-2" for="input-5">
        <!--                                <span class="input__label-content input__label-content-hoshi">Search...</span>-->
                                    </label>
                                        <span class="icon-serch"></span>

                                </span>
                                <input id="search-btn" type="submit" style="display: none;"/>
                                </form>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $('.search-wrapp .icon-serch').click(function(){
                                        $('#search-btn').trigger('click');
                                    })

                                </script>
                                <p class="in-cart">
                                    <span class="icon"></span>
                                    <span class="title">In cart:</span>
                                    <a href="/card" id="cart-header">
                                        <b class="Bouquet">Bouquet</b><span class="nubmer"> <?=$_SESSION['sum_count']?$_SESSION['sum_count']:0 ?></span>
                                        <b class="price-title">Price</b>
                                        <span class="price">$<?=$_SESSION['sum_count']?$_SESSION['sum_price']:0 ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="container">
                        <nav>
                            <div class="menu-icon">
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="flex-between-center menu">
                                <? $menu = $this->_db->select('catalog ', ' category = "main" AND active = 1 ORDER BY sort'); ?>
                                <? foreach ($menu as $item) {
                                if($item['id'] != 229){?>
                                        <li><a href="/catalog/<?= $item['link'] ?>" class="<?if($url->id == $item['link'])echo "active-menu";?>" ><?= $item['title_en'] ?></a></li>
                                <? }}?>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!-- end block1 -->
```

Can you help me with that? I think that I did not close ? Where Did I lose ? I can not understand it :( 
Thanks for help!

Comment: You need `4` more closing `</div>`'s at the end of your source. _Below: `<!-- end block1 -->`_

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close tag for the following:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="component">
```

So add 4 closing tag after `</section><!-- end block1 -->`

```
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="component">
        <section class="block1">
          <div class="container">
            <header class="flex-between-center">
              <div class="left">
                <p><span class="icon icon-map"></span>1620 Pebblewood Ln. Ste. 132
                  <br>Naperville, IL 60563
                </p>
                <a class="tel"><span class="icon icon-phone"></span><b>(630)741-4445</b></a>
                <div class="mob-tel">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="tel:(630)741-4445">(630) 741-4445</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="/">
                                    <img src="<?=CONFIG::TEMPLATE_ROOT?>design/img/logo.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <form action="/search">
                  <span class="input input--hoshi search-wrapp">
                                    <input class="input__field input__field--hoshi" type="text" id="search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search..."/>
                                    <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-2" for="input-5">
        <!--                                <span class="input__label-content input__label-content-hoshi">Search...</span>-->
                  </label>
                  <span class="icon-serch"></span>

                  </span>
                  <input id="search-btn" type="submit" style="display: none;" />
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  $('.search-wrapp .icon-serch').click(function() {
                    $('#search-btn').trigger('click');
                  })
                </script>
                <p class="in-cart">
                  <span class="icon"></span>
                  <span class="title">In cart:</span>
                  <a href="/card" id="cart-header">
                    <b class="Bouquet">Bouquet</b><span class="nubmer"> <?=$_SESSION['sum_count']?$_SESSION['sum_count']:0 ?></span>
                    <b class="price-title">Price</b>
                    <span class="price">$<?=$_SESSION['sum_count']?$_SESSION['sum_price']:0 ?></span>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="container">
            <nav>
              <div class="menu-icon">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </div>
              <ul class="flex-between-center menu">
                <? $menu=$ this->_db->select('catalog ', ' category = "main" AND active = 1 ORDER BY sort'); ?>
                <? foreach ($menu as $item) { if($item[ 'id'] !=2 29){?>
                <li>
                  <a href="/catalog/<?= $item['link'] ?>" class="<?if($url->id == $item['link'])echo " active-menu ";?>">
                    <?=$ item[ 'title_en'] ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <? }}?>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- end block1 -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

4 more closing `</div>` needed